# Bash Scripting for inseart .csv file in mysql with particular columns

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, csv, scripting

I have a csv file in that file there are more than 1 million data with 25 fields.
I want to insert only 20 fields in mysql

Fields are :

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
    `accountnum` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `custnum` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `accttype` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `classcode` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `classdesc` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `transdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `transcode` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `transdirect` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `transamount` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `acctopendate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `balance` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cashin` DOUBLE(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cashout` DOUBLE(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aliencustomer` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `foreignflag` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `originator` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `benefactor` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `naicscode` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `relatedAccount` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `relatedCIF` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `country` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `transid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cid` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '1838',
    `createts` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `datasetid` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `shortname` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

This is my sql table fields into that only I want to insert data in
`accountnum, custnum, accttype, classcode, classdesc, transdate, transcode, transdirect, transamount, acctopendate, balance, cashin, cashout, aliencustomer, foreignflag, originator, benefactor, naicscode, relatedAccount, shortname`.
in these fields i want to insert and when I will run the script particular that data i want get from the csv file.

Anyone please help me with the proper script how I can write a bash script in `ubuntu`?

Comment: Please also note that Indian numbers like lac (lakh) and crore are not widely understood outside of India and neighboring countries.